# Set TextBlock Text if Windows 10 uses dark theme (UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to set the text of a TextBlock if the windows 10 user uses the dark/light theme. I have tried

```
RequestedTheme == ElementTheme.Dark
```

but it doesn't work.

EDIT:
I want to set it like this

```
if(user uses dark them)
{
    mTextBlock.Text = "Dark"
}
elseif(user uses light theme)
{
   mTextBlock.Text = "Light"
}
```

Comment: Do you want to set the Text of TextBlock to Light/Dark or as the answer for this question?

Comment: @AVKNaidu yes for example

Comment: Can you show your full code as to how you are setting the Text to Textblock?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: That's more clear. See my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApplicationTheme` is an `Enum` for you to check what theme is imposed on your application. You can check like below.

```
if (Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark)
{
    mTextBlock.Text = "Dark"
}
elseif(Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Light)
{
   mTextBlock.Text = "Light"
}
```

More Information [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme)

Comment: That doesn't work. the TextBlock displays always "Light"

Comment: If you are on pre anniversary update, it will always be light because dark is not implemented. Also check your app.xaml for the theme. You might have set it to Light instead of Default.

Comment: My fault was that I set the RequestedTheme to Light. If i remove it, the code works as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"]
```

Comment: Just specify the [resource key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources#light-and-dark-theme-colors) like this shows, +1

Comment: The accent color and light/dark mode are two completely separate settings. The accent color tells you *nothing* about whether the system is in light or dark mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use {ThemeResource} markup extension to achieve what you want to do.
In your Page.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>                
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary2.xaml" x:Key="Dark"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" x:Key="Light"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{ThemeResource txt}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Dictionary1.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Styles">

<x:String x:Key="txt">Light</x:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Dictionary2.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Styles">

<x:String x:Key="txt">Dark</x:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```